# make a SELECT query add records outside my WHERE limits

Tags: sql-server, select

I've found it hard to describe in the title.

The issue is: i need to select records between 2 dates BUT i need to include the one record before the first date (which I don't know what date it has)

lest say I have records at:

- 15-12-2019
- 15-12-2019
- 16-12-2019
- 01-01-2020
- 05-01-2020
- 10-01-2020
- 15-01-2020
- 17-01-2020

I need to do a SELECT for a report between `01-01-2020 and 10-01-2020`, but the actual recordset should include `16-12-2019` as well, lets call it PADDING the results with 1 more record.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `UNION` with a second `SELECT` where you use `TOP 1` with records less than your minimum date and ordered in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had an index that led off on your date this would work as well:

```
CREATE TABLE #data (ID int, dt date)

INSERT INTO #data VALUES(1,'12-15-2019')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(2,'12-15-2019')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(3,'12-16-2019')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(4,'01-01-2020')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(5,'01-05-2020')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(6,'01-10-2020')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(7,'01-15-2020')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES(8,'01-17-2020')

DECLARE @fromDate date = '01-01-20'
DECLARE @toDate date = '01-10-20'

SELECT * FROM #data 
WHERE dt >=  (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM #data WHERE dt < @fromDate) and dt <= @toDate
```

Comment: Great! The simple and genius way. THank You

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM MyTable AS My
WHERE
    My.MyDate BETWEEN '2020-01'-01 AND '2020-01-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable AS My
WHERE 
    My.MyDate <'2020-01-01'
ORDER BY
    My.MyDate DESC
```